# Kotlin Unzipping Files

Tags: kotlin

Having troubles trying to figure out how to unzip a zip folder into /Documents/CardGameXXX/ I've tried just about every unzip example I can get my hands on, and either I get a crash or it just fails, any ideas.

Added : an example code of unzipping a zip file from https://mobikul.com/zip-unzip-file-folder-android-programmatically/ which doesn't work well it does, in the documents folder "CardGameXXX" folder is made and inside "Deck1" folder is created however everything stops there no files are extracted "Deck2" folder isn't even extracted, is this broken example code or have I royally messed something up here.

```
object ZipManager {
    private const val BUFFER_SIZE =  6 * 1024

    @Throws(
        IOException::class
    )
    
    fun unzip(zipFile: String?,location: String) {
        try {
            val f = File(location)
            if (!f.isDirectory) {
                f.mkdirs()
            }
            val zin = ZipInputStream(FileInputStream(zipFile))
            try {
                var ze: ZipEntry // = null
                while (zin.nextEntry
                        .also {
                            ze = it
                        } != null
                ) {
                    val path = location + File.separator + ze.name
                    if (ze.isDirectory) {
                        val unzipFile = File(path)
                        if (!unzipFile.isDirectory) {
                            unzipFile.mkdirs()
                        }
                    } else {
                        val fout = FileOutputStream( path,false )
                        fout.use { fout ->
                            var c: Int = zin.read()
                            while (c != -1) {
                                fout.write( c )
                                c = zin.read()
                            }
                            zin.closeEntry()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                zin.close()
            }
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.d("METAG","Unzip exception",e)
        }
    }
}

class Tools {

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Setup App Configuration
     */
    fun exSetupApp(AppContext: Context,AppContentResolver : ContentResolver ,folder : String)  {

        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "${Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS}/CardGameXXX/")
        AppContentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values)

        //
        // copy zip to documents/cardgamexxx folder somehow!?
        //
        // Copies the Assets.Zip into /cache
        val infileassetzip : String = getFileFromAssets(AppContext,"assets.zip").toString() // copy zip to cache folder
        //val target : String = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
        val target = File("/storage/emulated/0/Documents/CardGameXXX")

        // Now that it's in /cache unzip it from /cache to /Documents/CardGameXXX
        ZipManager.unzip(infileassetzip,target.toString())

        Log.d("METAG",infileassetzip)
        Log.d("METAG",target.toString())
        Toast.makeText(AppContext,"\"CardGameXXX\" created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        // defunt code but someday might feel useful!
        // Works, but crashes if already exists.
        //File(infileassetzip).copyTo(File("/storage/emulated/0/Documents/assets.zip"));
    }
}
```

Maybe this will help not sure, that said the file it says 'exists' on inspection with "Device File Explorer" it absolutely doesn't exist and never did.

> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/CardGameXXX/deck1/giphy.gif: open failed: EEXIST (File exists)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:236)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:157)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at com.example.cardgamexxx.ZipManager.unzip(MainActivity.kt:80)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at com.example.cardgamexxx.Tools.exSetupApp(MainActivity.kt:121)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at com.example.cardgamexxx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:366)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EEXIST (File exists)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7542)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
> 23074-23074/com.example.cardgamexxx W/System.err:   ... 20 more

Comment: My first guess is that Android won't grant you access to that directory. Try using one of the intended directories using `getCacheDir()` etc.

Comment: Getting cachedir isn't really the problem, the major snafu is unzip